# discord.py how to run command only if some reaction added

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make like a shop command, It's looks like this:
https://i.postimg.cc/2jcJT3r6/so.jpg
So i need to make like:
If `ctx.author` clicked on `:island:` reaction, buy the island.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) function:

```py
@bot.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test shop message")  # send a message
    emojis = ("️", "2️⃣", "3️⃣")
    for emoji in emojis:  # add reactions with all emojis
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    check = lambda payload: payload.message_id == message.id and payload.channel_id == ctx.channel.id and str(payload.emoji) in emojis
    payload = await bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', check=check, timeout=100)  # wait for user choose one of available items
    if str(payload.emoji) == "️":
        pass  # buy the island
    elif str(payload.emoji) == "2️⃣":
        pass  # buy the chest level 2
    elif str(payload.emoji) == "3️⃣":
        pass  # buy the chest level 3
```